# Is there any way to select column form table that has name as keyword from oracledb?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, keyword

There is a column LEVEL in table. Is there any way to select it? Like select LEVEL from table_name.

Answer (score 3):

Just put double quotes around the name:

```
SELECT MyTable."LEVEL" FROM MyTable;
```

If it's not too late in the game I'd recommend just changing the column name, but I know that's not always possible.

Also note that double quotes make the name case sensitive, so if you have a problem with `MyTable."LEVEL"` (all uppercase column name) you can find out the exact case of the column name like this:

```
SELECT Column_Name
FROM User_Tab_Columns
WHERE Table_Name = 'MYTABLE' AND UPPER(Column_Name) = 'LEVEL';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes "LEVEL" to escape the column.  This should fix your issue.